# Qml text element syntax error

Tags: qt, syntax-error, qml, qtquick2

I am getting the following-

```
file:///C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/Design1.qml:9:1: Syntax error 
     Text {

     ^
```

This is my very simple code yet I cannot get it to run in qmlviewer

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"
}

Text {
    id: Text1
    text: "Hello World!"
    y: 30
    anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
    font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found my problem it was that I forgot to make txt{} a child of Rectangle because there can only be one.

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {   // Indented
        id: text1
        text: "Hello World!"
        y: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with indentation.  It was because `Text` had to become a _child_ of the `Rectangle`, a QML file can only have one root object. Please correct your answer's description.

Answer (score 0):

`id`s can't have a capital letter at the beginning of the id name.

Change `Text1` to `text1` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks phyatt but I still have the same Syntax Error